# high-water mark distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, permutations

Given a sequence of values ${a_k}_{k=1}^n$, the high-water marks are the values at which the running maximum increases. For example, given a sequence $(3,5,7,8,8,5,7,9,2,5)$ with running maxima $(3,5,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)$, the high-water marks are $(3,5,7,8,9)$, which occur at $k=1, 2, 3, 4, 8$.

For every sequence $a_k$ there is a number of high-water marks $N_{a_k}$

Consider a set $\sigma$ of all permutations of $n$ numbers $(1, \dots, n)$. 
Does anybody knows the analytical expression for the distribution of the  number of high-water marks ($N_{a\in \sigma}$)?

For example, if $n=3$

$1,2,3 \rightarrow 3$
$1,3,2 \rightarrow 2$
$2,1,3 \rightarrow 2$
$2,3,1 \rightarrow 2$
$3,1,2 \rightarrow 1$
$3,2,1 \rightarrow 1$

and the distribution is $\left( \frac{2}{3!},\frac{3}{3!},\frac{1}{3!} \right)$.

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean distribution? Do you want a vector $1\times n$ with values in [0,1] saying the probability that that particular position is a max given a permutation which is uniformly sampled?

Comment: Could anyone explain downvoting? Is it standard known question? We need it for research purpose and where we should ask mathematical related questions if not in math stock exchange?

Comment: @mathreadler I want a vector $1 \times n$ with values in $[ 0, 1]$ for the fraction of permutations having specific number of high-water marks.

Comment: Sometimes people downvote if it is a question from a new user which does not show any own efforts in solving or finding references. This is mostly to avoid "please do my homework for me" type of behaviours. We would easily be flooded by lazy students if we did not punish it somehow. (i was the one who upvoted by the way)

Comment: Ok so it is the total number of max positions and not the probability of their positions.

Comment: I don't have any approach for solution right away, but it seems simulation-friendly...

Comment: @mathreadler, For every permutation there is a number of max positions, for example for $1,2,3 \rightarrow 3$, for $3,2,1 \rightarrow 1$. Im interested in a distribution of number of max positions - mapped values.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are after with this explanation in the comment. Maybe you can edit it into the question so it becomes a bit clearer to other people who read it.

Comment: Some probabilities are trivial to calculate, but the complete probability vector could be difficult to determine. For not too large $n$, brute force is feasible. For larger $n$, I suggest, as already mentioned , a Monte-Carlo-Simulation.

Comment: @Michelangelo Don't care about the downvotes. Many unjustified downvotes and close-votes but also many unjustified upvotes happen on this site. I am, by the way, the second up-voter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the cycle representation of a permutation (including the trivial one-element cycles). In each cycle, bring the greatest element to the front. Then order the cycles by these greatest elements, smallest first. If you now write down this cycle representation, ignore the parentheses and consider the resulting string as representing a permutation, precisely the greatest elements of the cycles are high-water marks in this permutation.

This establishes a bijection of the symmetric group with itself that maps between numbers of cycles and numbers of high-water marks. Thus the distribution of the number of high-water marks is the distribution of the number of cycles. This is given by the [unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).