# Arrangements of "skyscrapers" in which $n$ are visible

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

There is a logic puzzle called "Skyscrapers", in which you must place all numbers from $1$ to $n$ in each row and column of a square grid. Each number represents the height of a building at its location, and there are numbers given on the edges of the board that tell how many buildings are visible from that location. A building can only be seen if all buildings between it and the observer are shorter than it. Here's an example of a completed $4\times4$ puzzle:

[image]

This made me wonder: How many arrangements of $n$ buildings are there for which $k$ are visible? Meaning just from the point of view of one observer on, say, the left.

For $4$ buildings, it was easy enough to list the $24$ permutations and count how many buildings would be seen by an observer on the left. The breakdown of (# visible, # of permutations) is: $(1,6), (2,11), (3,6), (4,1)$.

Having just $1$ visible building is easy to explain: that's when the height-$4$ building is nearest to the observer. There are $3!=6$ ways to arrange the unseen shorter buildings.

Also, it's intuitive that $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the only arrangement with all $4$ visible.

But why are there $6$ and $11$ permutations in which $3$ and $2$ buildings are visible? I'm looking for a counting argument or a formula that can be used to explain why these are the answers. Ideally one that can be applied when there are more than $4$ buildings.

Comment: The number of permutations of $n$ buildings with $k$ visible buildings is equal to $n \brack k$, which is a Stirling number of the first kind. See previous questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827061/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624122/ for a proof.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: I think we should close both this question and one of those others as a duplicate of the remaining one?

Comment: @joriki I think the two questions I linked are not duplicates, because one is essentially asking for a proof that $\sum_{k=1}^n k{n \brack k}=n! H_n$, and the other is not.